LLMs, by their very nature, don't have a concept of "source" - is this true?
Summarize the problem
LLMs, by their very nature, don't have a concept of "source". Attribution is pretty much impossible. Attribution only really works if you use language models as "search engine". The moment you start generating output, the source is lost
Provide details and any research
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399619/our-partnership-with-openai/399621#comment1333377_399621

LLMs don't memorize text. They are supposed to generate text. So, by definition, the output will not necessarily follow what was exactly there in the train data, even if the train data contains sources, LLMs may/may not attribute those properly.


LLMs, by their very nature, don't have a concept of "source" - is this true?

Yes, because at training time, language models don't keep track of the sources. E.g., from the GPT paper:

Notes:

It's sometimes possible to guess the source, e.g. see How much of the ChatGPT output is copied from its training set (vs. being abstractively generated)?.
How can a language model keep track of the provenance of the main knowledge/sources used to generate a given output?


Surely it depends on the size of the tokens? The larger the tokens the easier it is to remember where they came from ... if whole sentences and paragraphs are used from a source then it is easy to see where the text has come from.

@user10186832 it's indeed possible to guess the source sometimes e.g. see How much of the ChatGPT output is copied from its training set (vs. being abstractively generated)?. But language models don't keep track of the sources.
